# I received an EOL error on a print line. Can anyone help me with it?

Tags: eol

I'm getting an EOL error and am unsure how to fix it.

My code is as follows:
print ("I'm so glad you feel " + emotion + ", " + username")

I get the following error
print ("I'm so glad you feel " + emotion + ", " + username")

Error: EOL while scanning string literal

Is anyone able to give me advice?

Edit: the arrow is under the final bracket

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print ("I'm so glad you feel " + emotion + ", " + username")`
with

`print ("I'm so glad you feel " + emotion + ", " + username)`.

It is because of trailing `"` , you must close `"` on the same line as you can see there is extra double quote after username!

> `"` must occur in pairs you must close a double quote after starting it!